# Create dictionary for classification dataset storage similar to digits dataset (sklearn)

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, machine-learning

I am extracting some features from some images and I would like to save them alongside their labels (and original images preferably) to be able to load them later without running the code for feature extraction every time.

I would like to store them in a  in a similar structure with the one from the `digits dataset` in `sklearn.datasets`, so that would be the `dictionary` type.

So my problem is not storing something of the type `key:value`, but something of the type:

- **features (X)**
- **target_labels (y)**
- **images** (optional)
- **target_names**

My `X` is `numpy.ndarray` data type and the `y` is `1-D vector array`.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it as `sklearn.datasets` methods return why don't you use their [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/412996f/sklearn/datasets/base.py#L29)?

They define a class `bunch` that does what you want:

```
class Bunch(dict):
    """Container object for datasets
    Dictionary-like object that exposes its keys as attributes.
    >>> b = Bunch(a=1, b=2)
    >>> b['b']
    2
    >>> b.b
    2
    >>> b.a = 3
    >>> b['a']
    3
    >>> b.c = 6
    >>> b['c']
    6
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Bunch, self).__init__(kwargs)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

    def __dir__(self):
        return self.keys()

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)
```

And then they create a dataset object with:

```
Bunch(data=data, target=target,
                 target_names=target_names,
                 DESCR=fdescr,
                 feature_names=['feat_1', 'feat_2',
                                'feat_3', 'feat_4'])
```